# How to merge 2 different jquery event functions?

Tags: jquery, click, keyup

I need to pass values from a text input and radio input fields, to a hidden text input. All works fine when entry is done individually but each replaces the other when triggered. I need to append the radio onto the text input.

```
$(function() {
  $("#text").keyup(function() {
    var text = ($("#text").val() != "" ? $("#text").val()+"," : "");
    $("#hidden").val(text);
  });
  $("input[name=radio]").click(function() {
    var radio = $("input[name=radio]:checked").val();
    $("#hidden").val(radio);
  });
});
```

### What I need as the output

```
$("#hidden").val(text + radio);
```

### What I tried

```
$(function() {
  $("#text").keyup(function() {
    var text = ($("#text").val() != "" ? $("#text").val()+"," : "");
  });
  $("input[name=radio]").click(function() {
    var radio = $("input[name=radio]:checked").val();
  });

  $("#hidden").val(text + radio);
});
```

But no values are returned.

**How** can I concatenate the output of **keyup()** and **click()** events?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57816566/edit) then `[<>]` stacksnippet editor and produce a [mcve] - you need to add the text and radio INSIDE the event handlers

Comment: try adding a hiddenText and a hiddenRadio input where you fill the text according to your logic. Then you can just combine these two hidden fields.

Comment: @nadal try my code, it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
function getText() {
  var text = [], val = $.trim($("#text").val()), $rad = $("input[name=radio]:checked");
  if (val) text.push(val);
  if ($rad.length >= 1) text.push($rad.val());
  $("#hidden").val(text.join(","));
}
$(function() {
  $("#text").on("input",getText);
  $("input[name=radio]").on("change",getText);
});
```

Comment: Excellent. However I prefer the simplicity of your previous method. My complete process is sending values of 18 fields to the single hidden field, so the more defensive coding would make it way more complex.

Comment: Then you could loop over field names when pushing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var radioValue="";
var text="";
$(function() {
  $("#text").keyup(function() {  
    text = ($("#text").val() != "" ? $("#text").val()+"," : "");
    if($("input[name='gender']:checked").val()!=undefined){
     checkedValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
    }
    else{
    checkedValue = ""
    }
    $("#hidden").text(text + "--" + checkedValue);
  });
  $("input[name='gender']").click(function() {
   textValue = $("#text").val();
    radioValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
    $("#hidden").text(textValue + "--" +radioValue);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="text"/><br/><br/>
 <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</label> 
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label><br/>
<label id="hidden" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your suggestion definitely works great, however the method by @mplungjan is extendable and simple, and is one which I had experimented previously but instead had created 2 separate custom functions. Many thanks.